# Reading com.fasterxml.jackson.core from resteasy-jackson-provider 3.9.0

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy, objectmapper, fasterxml

we are using Resteasy 3.9.0.Final in our vanilla java project. I have an api method which reads a POJO(`Request`) written in Jackson com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0.

```
    @Override
    @POST
    @GZIP
    @Path("/api")
    public Response call( @HeaderParam("host") @ApiParam(value = "host", required = true) String hostName,
            @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) Request request) {
```

But while reading it i get error -

```
“detailedErrorMessage”: “{\“messageDetails\“:\“Unrecognized field \\\“id\\\” (Class com.abc.api.platform.xyz.pqr), not marked as ignorable\\n at [Sou
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
```

But when I explicit read request in string and convert it into a `Request` class using ObjectMapper of Fasterxml then it works fine. How to force the api method to read POJO with FasterXML ObjectMapper instead of CodeHaus?

I have this in my dependency tree also

```
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.9.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile

org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile 
org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3.0:compile
```

Comment: Is upgrading to a newer version of RESTEasy an option?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No that is not an option right now.

Comment: Instead of the resteasy-jackson-provider try the resteasy-jackson2-provider. That would use the FasterXML version.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have one dependency which brings org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile, org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3.0:compile . Can they conflict with resteasy-jackson2-provider. I used  resteasy-jackson2-provider but it brings Unrecognized exception from jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd add a plugin as a dependency, but yes it might conflict. The `resteasy-jacksone2-providers` should not be bringing in Jackson 1 hence the name. Something else must be bringing that in.